case "define" then ^~~~^ Error: syntax error, unexpected case, expecting else or elseif or end
function [x, y, typ] = Kalman_Filter_IF(job, arg1, arg2)
    x = [];
    y = [];
    typ = [];
    getinput
    x0_set=[];
    covariance_matrix =[];
    
    select job
        // Initialize with mask parameters if any
        case "set" then
            x = arg1;
            graphics = arg1.graphics;
            exprs = graphics.exprs;
            model = arg1.model;
            
            if getInputFromSim==1 then
                exec("macros/Kalman_Filter_Utils.sci",-1);// Contains function declaration for this file
                title="Set Parameters";
                labels = ['Initial state [x_dot(velosity), x(position)] which is position in ECEF frame and velocity';'Covariance which gives the uncertainty at position and velocity'];  // Changed 'Stiffness' to 'Covariance'
                 // In future we can add ;'Accelerations';'Orientations which is obation altitude control system
                types = list('vec', 2, 'mat', 2);  // Changed 'vec' to 'mat' for Covariance
            // Create a dialog for getting user inputs
            while ~endLoop do
                // Initialize dialog for parameters and initial state
                [ok, Initial_state, covariance_matrix, exprs] = scicos_getvalue("Set Properties and State", labels, types, exprs);
                errMsg=[];
                // Check return // set conditions of the initial state as per meetings
                if ~ok then
                    // depends on what type of data we are having
                    if condition1 then // first condition of position and velocity
                        errMsg=[];
                    end 
                    
                    if condition2 then // second condition of velocity
                        errMsg=[];
                    end
                
                if isempty(errMsg)then 
                    [];// from here start working
                
                // Check parameters
                // You can add additional checks for input parameters here if needed
                
                // Accept inputs and save them
                if ok then
                    // Concatenate the covariance matrix to the state vector
                    model.state = [x0_set, covariance_matrix];  // Use the concatenation operator ":" for the matrix
                    graphics.exprs = exprs;
                    x.graphics = graphics;
                    x.model = model;
                    break;
                else
                    message("Failed to update block io");
                end
            end
            
        // Define block properties
        case "define" then
            // Create object
            model = scicos_model();
            // Provide name and type
            model.sim = list("Kalman_Filter_sim", 5);
            
            // Define inputs and outputs
            // One input with a variable-size "double" element
            model.in = [1]; // it's only z, 
            //it has at first position occupies which means at first position is 1, 1 indicates that only one input value, see wriiten notes to understand
            model.in2 = [1];   // the second dimension of I/P whcih means all the data enter has one dimension data for example just z axis data while if it was 2 than we have input data of x and y if there is 3 then x,y,z so on. each column represents specific data 
            model.intyp = 1;
            
            // One output with a single "double" element
            model.out = [2; 2];
            model.out2 = [1; 2];
            model.outtyp = 1;
            
                        // Set initial state
            model.state = [Initial_state; matrix(covariance_matrix, 4, 1)];   // Use the matrix concatenation function
            // For example: [initial_state; initial_covariance(:)]
            
            // Set default parameter
            model.rpar = covariance_matrix;  // Use the covariance matrix as a parameter
            
            // Define block properties
            model.blocktype = 'c';
            model.dep_ut = [%t %f]; // what does %t and %f indicates?
            
            // Set block properties
            exprs = ["[0.0; 0.0]"; "[1.0]"]; // How do we get this value?
            x = standard_define([4 4], model, exprs);
            x.graphics.style = ["blockWithLabel;displayedLabel=Kalman_Filter"];
            //other cases other than set or define sections
         end
endfunction


**exec('/Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/macros/Kalman_Filter_IF.sci', -1)
at line    59 of executed file /Users/vimalchawda/Desktop/spacecraft-gnc-tbx/macros/Kalman_Filter_IF.sci
    case "define" then
    ^~~~^

Error: syntax error, unexpected case, expecting else or elseif or end**
I am trying to resolve syntax error as sometimes it is difficult to visualise it. I tried to find out the error.
